# How to remove '\r' from UTF-16LE file?

Tags: python, utf

I have a file that is encoded with `UTF-16le`

```
$ file -bi Foo.csv 
text/plain; charset=utf-16le
```

Each line ends with `\r\n`. And I want to remove `\r` while converting file to `UTF-8`.

So the question is do I need to delete just `\r` or `\r\x00`?

Comment: what happens if you try?  (I would guess its more liek \x00\x0d assuming you are forced to use all the bits)

Comment: How are you reading the file into Python? If you're using text mode and decoding to `unicode` objects, you should end up with sensible line endings.

Comment: Have you tried `open("Foo.csv", "rU")`? http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @nmclean Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was looking for. It should be an answer )